# ExpandableListView Adapter List<object>

Tags: android, adapter, expandablelistview

I receive to send to my `ExpandableListViewAdapter` List. Inside have `String title` and another list.

I'm following this guide http://www.androhub.com/android-expandablelistview/ but don't know how receive (on adapter constructor) my list to show the ExpandableListView

I tried this:

```
private List<MyClass> dat;
private Context _context;
private List<String> header, a;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> child;

 public TestAdapter(Context _context, List<MyClass> dat) {
    this._context = _context;
    this.dat = dat;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> hashMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    for(int i = 0; i<dat.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < dat.get(i).getDestinations().size(); j++){
            a.add(dat.get(i).getDestinations().get(j).getTitle());
        }
        header.add(dat.get(i).getTitle());
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<header.size(); i++){
        hashMap.put(header.get(i), a);
    }
}
```

But not work.

Comment: You have to create a hashmap with data type for your header items and your child item list

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/ check this out

Answer (score 3):

Go with this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/).. The explanation is much better..